# I want to draw a cartesian product of complete graphs.Something like the below picture

Tags: nodes, graphs

[image]

I have a small code. With which I can draw a square, but I'm unable to draw the second square and join the corresponding vertices

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Why not show your small code? Make it as complete small document, which we can copy to our computers and compile. With it not to need start from scratch ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you liked:

[image]

Above picture is generated by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {draw=black, minimum size=2cm},
        node distance = 2cm]
\node (A) {};
\node (B) [right=of A] {};

\foreach \pos [count=\i] in {north west, north east, south west, south east}
{
    \fill[gray] (A.\pos) circle (2mm) (B.\pos) circle (2mm);
\ifnum\i<3
    \draw[green, thick] (A.\pos) to [bend left=30] (B.\pos);
\else
    \draw[green, thick] (A.\pos) to [bend right=30] (B.\pos);
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In above code I exploit TikZ library `positioning` by which the second node is positioned for `node distance` right of the first one. Circles and Green arcs are drawn by `\foreach` loop, where defined positions of circles and with additional counter `\i` are used in drawing arcs: for above two is used `bend=left` and for second two `bend=right`.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum size=2cm,draw, black] (A) at (0,0){};
\node[minimum size=2cm,draw, black] (B) at (4,0){};

\foreach \pos/\bend in {north east/left, south east/right, north west/left, south west/right}{
\draw[fill] (A.\pos) circle (0.1);
\draw[fill] (B.\pos) circle (0.1);
\draw[green, thick] (A.\pos) to [bend \bend=20] (B.\pos);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The lower green arcs should bend to the outside according to the image in the question. For example, it can be fixed by using angles (45, 135, 225, 315) instead of directions. Then `bend left` and `bend right` can be selected depending on the angle, the option can then dynamically be calculated: `bend \ifnum\pos<180 left\else right\fi=20`

Comment: I adapted the code with a loop two variables